# Create textbox while running the program

Tags: revit-api

is it possible to create a text box just like in the follow image ?
[image]

Comment: Directly on a Revit ribbon? via Revit api?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look into Undocumented AdWindows.dll that Jeremy Tammik mentioned on his site.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.